# How to use udp protocol to send http request?

Tags: java, http, udp

I'm working on a problem:

The server side of my project support `queue processing` of wrapper `http` in udp packet, means that I just need to send the `udp datagrampacket` contains the http format request, and need not care about the respond of this request.

please help me know how to implement the http using the wrapper of udp datagrampacket?.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Did you try something? Show us.

Comment: As I know http over UDP is not good practice. Because you should handle lost packets by your own in service layer, but over TCP it's handled in transport layer. Why do you need http over UDP?